# Using a non-static value in a static method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am currently using the sample app from https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le, which shows data from a sensor in real-time.  My goal now is to display a chart with this data, so I am using the Microcharts package. When using the following code with static data (and declaring the List as static) the chart works fine, but, when I try to use the real-time data (CharacteristicValue) I get the errors:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CharacteristicDetailViewModel.entries'
> Error  CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'CharacteristicDetailViewModel.CharacteristicValueTemp'

I understand that this is happening because the data is changing, but I wonder if there is any workaround I could use to display the data in real-time?

In my ViewModel I have:

```
 public List<ChartEntry> entries = new List<ChartEntry>
     {
         new ChartEntry(CharacteristicValue)
         {
             Color=SKColor.Parse("#FF1943"),
             Label ="January",
             ValueLabel = "200"
         },
         new ChartEntry(400)
         {
             Color = SKColor.Parse("00BFFF"),
             Label = "March",
             ValueLabel = "400"
         },

     };
```

And in the .xaml.cs file:

```
 public CharacteristicDetailPage()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();

        ChartTest.Chart = new LineChart() 
            {
                Entries = CharacteristicDetailViewModel.entries,
                LineMode = LineMode.Straight,
                LineSize = 8,
                PointMode = PointMode.Square,
                PointSize = 18,
            };
    }
```

(Yes, I know this chart makes no sense right now, I just wannna make the updating work before it gets more complicated)

Thank you! :)

Comment: i think in the end you have to rebind the data, so no need for a static list is needed.
And then you just use model binding ect. 
take also a look here: https://github.com/dotnet-ad/Microcharts/issues/30

Comment: static and readonly aren't the same things. I think you're confusing the two here. A static list can change its contents. Unless you also declare it readonly.

Comment: @Isparia Hi, were you ever able to make this code work? I've tried dozens of times but I never get what the "myApi" supposed to be,  I have tried many variables but nothing works with the GetValuesAssync().  I tried to just use a float[] as the values but I get no chart on the screen

Comment: You need to make the called member static .

Answer (score 0):

`CharacteristicDetailViewModel.entries` is not a static member. You need a concrete instance of a `CharacteristicDetailViewModel`:

```
var myCharacteristicDetailVM = /*some initializing or retrieval logic of a concrete instance of the VM*/
```

And then:

```
ChartTest.Chart = new LineChart() 
{
    Entries = myCharacteristicDetail.entries /*a concrete instance of the VM*/, 
    LineMode = LineMode.Straight,
    LineSize = 8,
    PointMode = PointMode.Square,
    PointSize = 18,
};
```

That said, you seem to have a deep misunderstanding about what `static` actually means in c#. I suggest you read up on the subject [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

Comment: Hi, I am not very sure I understood what you meant by *some initializing or retrieval logic of a concrete instance of the VM*, but I suppose something like var myCharacteristicDetailVM = new CharacteristicDetailViewModel();? I remember following some binding tutorials in the past where I was supposed to write this at some point but, since I am working with Bluetooth, this function actually needs an adapter so I still could not make it work :s  https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/master/Source/BLE.Client/BLE.Client/ViewModels/CharacteristicDetailViewModel.cs (the full viewmodel)